# Pushing a vector of pointers into a std::map

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, maps

A part of my code runs a for loop generating a pointer to a class and each time the for loop pushes the generated pointer to a vector of pointer type.

```
std::vector<class_X*>strvecptr;
std::map<int32,std::vector<class_X*>> MapStrPtr;
for(int32 key=0;key<5;key++)
{
for(int32 i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    class_X* ptr = new class_X* (i);

    \\ do some calculations

    strvecptr.push_back(ptr);

}
MapStrPtr[Key].push_back(strvecptr);

}
```

Pusing into map throws an error

```
C2664: std::vector<_Ty>::push_back : cannot convert parameter 1 from std::vector<_Ty> to class_X* const &
```

I am confused as how to push this into the map.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want just `MapStrPtr[key] = myFilledVector;`?

Comment: Yes, but *what* do you want to push there? If you are going to push_back each element one by one, it's pointless, you can copy the whole vector into the map.

Comment: Yes. I want to store all pushed vector of pointers be stored according to certain key values in my map

Comment: i am a bit puzzled why you posted pseudo code. `for(int i=0;i<10;++i)` isnt much more to type than `for(loop on i)`, but it is real code. Same for `new class_X* (arg depends on i);` vs `new class_X (i);` (also note the `*` !). Please read about [mcve]

Comment: I apologize for not producing a minimal reproducible example. I will correct it in my next posts. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: you dont have to wait for the next post. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58854384/edit) this question so we can know what you are actually doing

Comment: I kind of did now. I hope it satisfies

Comment: still one thing is fishy. There is no `pushback` method. Is this really the exact error message literally?

Comment: `class_X* ptr = new class_X*(i)` is invalid. `new class_X*` returns a `class_X**`.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact error message. The pushback call is the usual std::vector member function available. Its template goes like this

void push_back (const value_type& val);

Comment: What is this `pushback` in both the code and the error message? Appears to be made up...

Comment: I did type the error message changing the class names to what I have in the code snippet above. The error reads as like this in Visual Studio 2008

Comment: @lebesgue You have some answers, including mine. You really need to comment on those if they answer your question, or if they've misunderstood you. Your question could be interpreted in different ways. So provide feedback on the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your map does not contain the vector itself, but should instead hold the `class_X*`.

Change this:

```
std::map<int32_t, std::vector<class_X*>> MapStrPtr;
```

To

```
std::map<int32_t, class_X*> MapStrPtr;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused as how to push this into the map.

You don't `push_back` to insert the vector into the map. You insert the whole vector in one go for a given key.

Change

```
MapStrPtr[key].pushback(strvecptr);
```

to

```
MapStrPtr[key] = strvecptr;
```

---

Edit following OP comment:

> What happens if I want to push a entry for the same key value?

Then you will get the existing stored vector for the key, and `push_back` onto it a pointer to an instance of `class_X`.

```
MapStrPtr[key].pushback(ptr);
```

Comment: the maps mapped_type is a vector, so `MapStrPtr[key].pushback(strvecptr);` could be correct assuming `strvecptr` are of type `class_x*`. Unfortunately the question is rather unclear...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 `strvecptr` is not `class_x*` as per OP post as of now.

Comment: @P0W That's why the question is unclear. We don't know if OP wants to keep a copy of vector in map or push elements of this vector to the vector in map.

Comment: @P0W its only in the error message, but that is obviously not from the posted code. But well, I see what you mean, only now I saw it in the error message. Nevertheless "You don't/can't push_back to a map." is misleading, because `MapStrPtr[key].pushback(strvecptr);` is not trying to push into the map. It is trying to push `strvecptr` into the mapped value for key `key` inside the map.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen What OP wants, only OP knows and can tell, but right not he has the declaration for `strvecptr `.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 OP is trying to 'push", which is the wrong choice of word OP should either `insert` or use the overloaded `[]` as this answer says. However, the answer is not very desirable (though not wrong, given limited information), I didn't downvote nor I like to upvote since we could use smart pointers here.

Comment: @P0W they did use `operator[]` which returns reference to a vector and then calls `push_back` on that... no need to split hairs further, OP edited with real code

Comment: @acraig5075 What happens if I want to push a entry for the same key value?